# matplotlib - chart wont update unless window is moved

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib

I've created a matplotlib chart and it will not update until I move the window it's plotted in (Qwidget). I was wondering would anyone know of why this might be and how to fix it? The initial figure is created within a constructor method as follows:

```
        self.fig1 = Figure()
        self.ax1 = self.fig1.add_subplot(111)
        self.addmpl(self.fig1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the following line of code:

```
self.mpl_canvas.draw()
```

Thanks for your help